# How to optimize massive amounts of data in mysql tables using a join

Tags: performance, query-optimization, inner-join

Perhaps using a JOIN isn't the best option here, but here's the scenario:

I have two tables, one is for houses, the other for objects in that house.

I have 50 houses and 8000 objects.

Lastly, each object will be either black or white (boolean).

Each object must be associated with each house and each object must be either black or white, which means, through my current design, there are going to be 400,000 records (8,000 ones, 8,000 twos all the way up to 50) in the objects table! Not the best for optimization. And my site turned into geriatric snails smoking ganja when I tried to load the query on my webpage. It died.

The table I have for houses looks like this:

```
==============================
House| Other cols | Other cols
==============================
1    |            |
2    |            | 
3    |            |
4    |            | 
to 50
```

The table I have for objects looks like this:

```
============================
House_ID | Object | Color
============================    
1        | 1      | 1
1        | 2      | 1
1        | 3      | 0
1        | 4      | 1
1        | 5      | 0
```

"House_ID" increments to 2 once "Object" reaches 8,000. This incrementing continues until House_ID reaches 50.

There must be a better way to create an association between the house and the objects where each object must have that specific house ID and it is not quite so taxing on the server.

BTW, I'm using an INNER JOIN to combine both tables. I think this might be wrong, but don't know a way around it. Doing SQL queries in phpMyAdmin.

How would I join or set up my table/queries so that it's not so cumbersome?

Comment: Please show queries to be optimized, and the database name, and it's version. Please also complement tags and add a tag for your DBMS. Are there any indexes created on these two tables ? Are there appropriate primary keys definied?.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to investigate indexing your tables. This is actually a fairly small data set for what you are doing.

If your table names are houses and objects, try:

```
CREATE INDEX houses_index ON houses (House)
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX house_objects_index ON objects (HouseID,Object)
```

This will make your queries run MUCH faster, if, as I presume, indexes do not already exist.

(You might also want to keep you column names consistent between tables; calling the field House in one table and HouseID in another is, I think, more confusing than calling it HouseID both places.)

Comment: By the way, creating the indexes can be slow, but it will speed things up afterwords.